# How to fix Array to string conversion Issue in PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, arrays

### Details

- I have 6 continent_id  = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 }
- I want it to loop 6 times and print out the appropriate continent name in stead.

### Here what I have tried

```
<?php 

foreach(array_unique(array_values($continent)) as $continent_id){

    if($continent_id == 1 ){ $continent == "Europe" ; } 
    elseif ($continent_id == 2 ){ $continent == "Asia" ; } 
    elseif ($continent_id == 3 ){ $continent == "North America" ; } 
    elseif ($continent_id == 4 ){ $continent == "Oceania" ; } 
    elseif ($continent_id == 5 ){ $continent == "South America" ; } 
    else { $continent == "Africa" ; } 



    echo '<h1>#'.$continent."</h1>";
```

### Here is what I get

I got this error message

Array to string conversion (View: C:\wamp\www\distributor-application\laravel\app\views\jsons\decoding.blade.php)

Can someone tell me what I missed ?

Comment: Here you use $continent as an array: array_values($continent) Here you compare it to a string: $continent == "Asia".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing with `$continent == "Europe"`

when you want to assign `$continent = "Europe"`

do that change and the same for the others.

Comment: I would have mentioned that he should rename the second $continent variable to avoid future confusion with the code.

Comment: Most of the times it's the other way around :D